# Test for polynomial reducibility with binary coefficients

Tags: polynomials, galois-theory

I'm learning about Galois Fields, in particular $GF(2^8)$, as they are applied to things like the [AES](http://csrc.nist.gov/publications/fips/fips197/fips-197.pdf) algorithm and [Reed-Solomon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reed_Solomon) codes.  Each of these rely on an irreducible 8th degree polynomial with binary coefficients to serve as a modulus for generating the particular field instance.  For example AES uses $x^8+x^4+x^3+x^1+x^0$.

Is there a test I can apply to an 8th degree polynomial with binary coefficients I am presented with to determine whether or not it is irreducible?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berlekamp's_algorithm

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Thanks for the link.  It looks like Berlekamp's algorithm will find the factors of a polynomial which is a bit of overkill for my application.  I'm not necessarily interested in finding the factors (unless there's no other way to determine reducibility), only determining whether or not the polynomial is irreducible.

Comment: Do you want something you can do by hand or something that you can write an efficient algorithm implementing? For the latter you can compute $\gcd(f(x), x^{2^n} - x)$ for various $n$ less than or equal to the degree of $f$. The factors of $x^{2^n} - x$ are precisely the irreducible polynomials of degree dividing $n$ so this is guaranteed to determine if $f$ has a nontrivial factor or not, and you can make this pretty efficient by computing $x^{2^n} - x$ using binary exponentiation $\bmod f(x)$ (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A non-irreducible polynomial $p(x)$ of degree eight has an irreducible factor of degree $\le 4$. This suggest the following test. Check divisibility by all of $x$, $x+1$, $x^2+x+1$, $x^3+x+1$, $x^3+x^2+1$, $x^4+x+1$, $x^4+x^3+1$ and $x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1$. That list contains all the irreducible polynomials of degree $\le 4$ with coefficients in $GF(2)$. If your polynomial is not divisible by any of these, it is irreducible.

That is a little bit of work. Of course testing divisibility by either $x$ or $x+1$ is trivial. A polynomial is divisible by $x$, iff its constant term is zero. And a binary polynomial is divisible by $x+1$, iff it has an even number of terms. The remaining six are a bit trickier. Often checking for divisibility by $x^2+x+1$ is aided by the observation that $x^3+1=(x+1)(x^2+x+1)$ is divisible, hence so are all binomials of the form $x^\ell+x^{\ell+3}$. This allows you to replace a high degree term with a lower degree term. Similarly the cubic irreducible ones are both factors of $x^7+1$, but that won't be nearly as useful in the calculations.

Comment: As a practical matter, one could just look in tables of irreducible polynomials over $\mathbb F_2$ to see if the degree-$8$ polynomial is listed therein. I suppose one could call this a test: the polynomial is irreducible if and only if it appears in the table. Some tables list the polynomials in lexicographical order which makes the test even easier.

Comment: @DilipSarwate:  That's probably what I'll eventually end up doing in the long run.  In the near term, I still have to figure out which ones are and are not irreducible.

Comment: Actually the fact that the cubic irreducible are factors of $x^7+1$ is very helpful here because it means you can replace $x^8$ with $x$ without changing divisibility, and this leaves the remainder as $x^4+x^3+1$ which is on the list of irreducibles. So neither cubic irreducible is a factor.