# Show that $x^{8}+x^{4}+x^{3}+x+1$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Z}_{2}[x]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, irreducible-polynomials

How do I show that $x^{8}+x^{4}+x^{3}+x+1$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Z}_{2}[x]$? Someone says I should use the fact that the range of the matrix is 7, but I don't exactly know how that applies. Thanks for any input.

Comment: I'm fairly sure that this has been explained on the site already. After all this polynomial is specified in AES/Rijndael cryptosystem. Have you searched the site?

Comment: I gave extended hints for proving this in [this thread](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/391787/11619). Can you follow those instructions? All: I'm a bit hesitant in closing this as a duplicate lest I give the impression that I want to call undue attention to my own answer. It would not surprise me at all, if an earlier thread about this polynomial existed :-)

Comment: Thanks by the reference and comments Jyrki Lahtonen, however is there a connection related with the range of the matrix?

Comment: What matrix? :-)

Comment: perhaps it is a wrong approach but the matrix that I am talking is the matrix associated with this polynomial regarded as the characteristic polynomial of that matrix.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: Note it has no roots. List all the irreducibles of degree 4 or less. Division.

With degree 4, it's not enough to test for absence of roots.